# Characterization of normal space

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to show that a Frechet Topological space $(X,\tau)$ is normal if and only if for every closed subset B and every open set $U(B)$ that contains B there exists another open subset $V(B)$ that contains B such that $\overline{V(B)} \subseteq U(B)$. 
What i've tried so far for the $\rightarrow$ direction is to consider $(X-U(B))$ which is closed and then take an open set $V(X-U(B))$ which exists because it is a normal space I think that $X/(V(X/U(B))) \subseteq U(B)$ but I am not sure about this. For the other direction I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B \subseteq U(B)$ we indeed consider the disjoint closed subsets $B$ and $X\setminus U(B)$. There are disjoint open $V(B) \supseteq B$ and $W(B)\supseteq X\setminus U(B)$. The last inclusion can also be written equivalently as $X\setminus W(B) \subseteq U(B)$ and as $V(B)$ and $W(B)$ are disjoint we have $V(B) \subseteq X\setminus W(B)$.

Hence $B \subseteq V(B) \subseteq \overline{V(B)} \subseteq \overline{X\setminus W(B)} = X\setminus W(B) \subseteq  U(B)$ as required, using that $X\setminus W(B)$ is closed.

The other direction is similar: suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed sets, then we apply the condition to the closed set $A$ and its open neighbourhood $X\setminus B$ and get $V$ open with $A \subseteq V$ and $\overline{V} \subseteq X\setminus B$, and it's then easy to check that $V$ and $X\setminus \overline{V}$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $A$ and $B$ respectively.